# getting hidden files like .statuses of whatsapp in expo

Tags: reactjs, native

Good day, I am trying to get Status using expo media library but it seems that all the albums returned does not contain whatsapp status

```html
const permissions = await requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync(uriDir);
      const a  = await getAlbumsAsync({includeSmartAlbums:true})
      console.log({a})
      const allAlbumsId = await getAlbumAsync('Whatsapp Status')
      const assetsInAlbum = await getAssetsAsync({album:allAlbumsId});
      let finalArray =assetsInAlbum.assets;
      setUri(finalArray[1].uri)
      console.log({allAlbumsId})
      console.log({allAlbums:finalArray})
```